# how to implement trigger logic? if value [1] is part of insert, populate other table with other value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following insert trigger, which is essentially writing a duplicate row from an insert to a QA/QC table (IAW business requirement).

```
  INSERT dbo.TBL_LOCATIONS(
  Column1, Column2
  )
  SELECT 
  a.Column1,  a.Column2
  From
  (  
    SELECT  
   Column1,   Column2
     FROM inserted  
  ) AS a 
  end
GO
```

What I'm trying to do is populate `[Column1]` in `tbl_locations` with a range of values based on a logic test of the possible values being inserted in the insert table,e.g. if `[a.Column1]` is "1", then insert "Some string" in `tbl_locations.Column1`, if `[a.Column1]` is "2", then insert "Some other string" in `tbl_locations.Column1`,if `[a.Column1]` is "3", then insert "Yet another string" in `tbl_locations.Column1`...

Comment: if you have a SubType modelled it should probably have its own table...

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a `CASE` expression to perform a simple translation from one set of values to another.  It's also a little unclear why your selecting your selected data redundantly again.

Comment: "When this value is inserted in this tbl,  want to see this value updated in this tbl". As far as the business rules, this question is part of a bigger picture, where  inserts, updates, and deletes are replicated to table a;table x,y,z are the tables that div. x,y,z use to track products x,y,z and management uses tbl a for the "view" of all products.  division x,y, and z staff could care less, they want to perform their adds, deletes, and updates on their tblsand let management figure out what they're up to by looking at tbla. the inserts logic is working great, I now need to address updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TBL_LOCATIONS (Column1, Column2)
SELECT
  s.Description,
  i.Column2
FROM inserted i
LEFT JOIN (
  VALUES
    (1, 'Polygon: Determination Made by GPS Survey'  ),
    (2, 'Polygon: Determination Derived from NWI'    ),
    (3, 'Polygon: Determination Made by Other Means' ),
    (4, 'Polygon: Legal Jurisdictional Determination')
) s (ID, Description)
ON i.Column1 = s.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         INSERT dbo.TBL_LOCATIONS( 
          Column1, Column2 
          ) 
          SELECT  
          a.Column1,  a.Column2 
          From 
          (   
            SELECT   
           Column1= case
        when Column1= 1 then 'Polygon: Determination Made by GPS Survey'
        when Column1= 2 then 'Polygon: Determination Derived from NWI' 
        when Column1= 3 then 'Polygon: Determination Made by Other Means'
        when Column1= 4 then 'Polygon: Legal Jurisdictional Determination'
        end ,
        Column2 
             FROM inserted   
          ) AS a  
          end 
GO
```